# how to plot correlation of two images in Matlab

Tags: matlab, math, image-processing, signal-processing

Need to plot nonlinear correlation between two images. The output is a sharp peak when the images are same. If images are different we get a scattered plot on surface.

The formula for this correlation is:

```
abs ( IFT( {FT(img1) FT(img2)} x       {FT(img1) FT(img2)} / abs(FT(img1) FT(img2)) )  ).^2
```

The required output is shown in pictures PIC 1 [similar vs dissimilar](https://i.stack.imgur.com/04QA8.png)

The plots described by Maurits can be plotted using xcorr2() of Matlab. I plot for similar and dissimilar image as shown : PIC 2 [xcorr2 plots](https://i.stack.imgur.com/D9yuc.png)

However I want the curve with sharp peaks  as shown in the PIC 1

Here is the code I wrote:

```
a=imread('pepper.tiff')
b=imread('cameraman.tiff')

Fa=fftshift(fft2(a))
Fb=fftshift(fft2(b))
z= abs (ifft2( (Fa.*Fb)  .* (Fa.*Fb) ./ abs(Fa.*Fb)   )  );
surf(abs(z))
```

But i get a crazy curve and not like the ones int the original picture. Any one familiar with nonlinear correlation plots?
Thanks

Comment: Your equation and your code don’t match at all. The equation uses the FT of each input image three times, in your code you use them only once.

Comment: I know, i was just trying to state what i tried.

Comment: So what is stopping you from implementing that equation? I don’t understand your question. You have the equation, you had code that computed the FT part and the multiplication, have you tried extrapolating from that?

Answer (score 0):

It seems you forgot the conjugate, i.e

```
% assuming your images are the same size
size_t = size(im_a);
% padding size
outsize = 2*size_t - 1;

%   FFT 
Fa = fft2(im_a, outsize(1), outsize(2));
Fb = fft2(im_b, outsize(1), outsize(2));

% Cross correlation
c = abs( fftshift( ifft2(Fa .* conj(Fb))) );
```

For normalized crosscorrelation you can use [normxcorr2](https://www.mathworks.com/help/images/ref/normxcorr2.html). The matlab help page contains the formula used and links to the relevant papers.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I tried to use your code but the surf plot for both cases (similar and dissimilar images) is the same. Can you try to output as shown in the attached picture above and help me realize the code. I even tried your code with the actual formula but the plots are not sharp peaks its more like a inverted bowl curve

Comment: @liwei You need to share the original images then.

Comment: Please check my first post, i have edited two pictures PIC 1 is the desired plot output and PIC 2 is the one as you described, seems like i can find that using xcorr2() method of Matlab

Comment: @Cris Luengo Thank you for the push :D I tried the above code I have edited in the orignal post but doesnt seem to work. Can you check any changes to make?